# Java library for command line Code Coverage calculation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I am writing a Java program (using swing UI) that takes a java program (.java file with main function) and an excel file of large number of test cases as input.

It then uses Genetic Algorithm to return a limited size small subset of test cases that are best according to a criteria.

On of these criteria is Code Coverage.

I can easily write a fitness function that runs a command in cli and reads output. The only problem is that I need a tool that runs in command line and returns the value of code coverage (of bytecode or any other level). My fitness function will read this code coverage value and then try to maximize it for the entire subset.

Bottom line:-
I need a tool to check code coverage of *.java files.

There are 2 classes in my case:-

TestingClass.java

```
import interest_calculator.CompoundInterest;

public class TestingClass {

    static CompoundInterest obj;
    public static final int ARGS_COUNT = 3;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        initializeClass();
        setValues( args );
        printResult();
    }

    private static void initializeClass() {
        obj = new CompoundInterest();
    }

    private static void setValues( String[] args ) {
        obj.principle = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        obj.rate = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        obj.time = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
    }

    private static void printResult() {
        System.out.println( obj.calcCompoundInterest() );
    }

}
```

CompoundInterest.java (in a subfolder "interest_calculator"):-

```
package interest_calculator;

public class CompoundInterest {

    public double principle;
    public double rate;
    public double time;

    public double calcCompoundInterest() {
        double ci = principle * ( java.lang.Math.pow((1 + rate / 100), time) );
        ci = round( ci, 2 );
        return ci;
    }

    public double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
        value = value * factor;
        long tmp = Math.round(value);
        return (double) tmp / factor;
    }

}
```

I need a tool that lets me call TestingClass from commandline using three commandline arguments and returns me code coverage of any kind (Literally Any Kind). I just need to demonstrate working of a Genetic Algorithm for code coverage.

Is there any suh tool. And how exactly do I use that tool for calculating code coverage with commandline arguments to my program.

The genetic algorithm is working for other criteria by the way. I am using [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/) library for this purpose.

Comment: *code covergar* means nothing, especially with application level Tests like you do in fittness. Much more important is *requirements coverage* which you cannot measure unfortunately. **---** Having said this: did you have a look at [cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/)?

Comment: Lol - I can tell you the code coverage only by looking at your code. Your main class has 100%, the other one 0%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two commonly used code coverage tools for Java [Cobertura](https://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/) and [Jacoco](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/). Typically these are used to measure unit tests and have tight integration with build tools such as maven and gradle. There are a couple of options for you:

1. If you are using a build tool e.g. maven or gradle, you can create a build target that runs your test class (with the appropriate arguments) and then insert this at the right point to have the coverage measured.
2. You could refactor the tests to be JUnit tests, this would ensure that coverage could be measured in the usual way for the two tools mentioned.
3. You can measure code coverage at Runtime of your application. This can be done through Jacoco which will instrument the JVM rather than the class files.

Based on your question I believe that option 3 is the one that you are looking for. DZone have a [tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/code-coverage-report-generator-for-java-projects-a) that explains how to achieve this.